# Getting a hDib from a CBitmap*

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I have a Bitmap* (this is Visual C++ 6.0).

I need to save this Bitmap* to a bmp file. I've seen code on the internet that allows me to do this if I have an hDib. (handle to Dib). Given that I already have a CBitmap*, how can I obtain the hDib?

Or, if someone has an easier way to save a bitmap to a file, that would be great too. (This is VC++ 6.0 (1998) and I don't (think) I have access to CImage.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume you're actually asking about CBitmap and not Bitmap, as they're two different things.

CBitmap derives from CGdiObject, which has a member m_hObject that contains the handle.

It also has an `operator HBITMAP` which returns the handle - all you have to do is a cast.

```
HBITMAP hbmp = (HBITMAP) mybitmap;
```

Whether this handle is a DIB or not will depend on how you created the bitmap.